# Sorting NSMutablearray by NSString as a date

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, sorting

I have an array, which is filled out with string objects. Inside each object is the name of the object and the string, seperated by " - ", ex. "Object1 - 26.05.2012 ". I would like to sort my array by the date in the string, and not the name, descending Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible of course, but probably parsing the date out of the name and store it in the object separately will be more optimal

Comment: Read through the list of sort options for `NSArray`.  There are a couple that would work for you.  Non-trivial, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Vladimir pointed out, it would be much better to separate the name and the string from each other and sort by the date.

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
for (NSString *str in yourArray)
{
    NSRange rangeForDash = [str rangeOfString:@"-"];
    NSString *objectStr = [str substringToIndex:rangeForDash.location];
    NSString *dateStr = [str substringFromIndex:rangeForDash.location+1];
    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateStr];
    NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:objectStr, @"object", date, @"date", nil];
    [newArray addObject:dic];
}
NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
[newArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDesc, nil]];
[sortDesc release];
[formatter release];
```

`newArray` will be sorted but will have dictionary objects, each containing 2 strings.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty fix - rearrange the string so that the date is first

`str = [[str substringFromIndex:someIndex] stringByAppendingString:[str substringToIndex:someIndex]];`

then just switch everything back once the array is sorted.